# Simple object sample in java

Tags: java, object

Variable could not be found error coming while I am trying to access `m.name = "killer"` inside the class. Please, help.

```
class Movie {

     String name;
     String genre;
     int num;

     public void play()
     {
         System.out.println("start playing");
     }
}

public class MovieObjects{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MovieObjects m = new MovieObjects ();
        {
            m.name="Killer"; 
            m.genre = "Romance";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner braces are wrong but harmless.

Comment: its Movie m = new Movie(); not MovieObjects m = new MovieObjects ();

Comment: Do something about your indentation and please go through some tutorials on Java basic before posting such questions here.

Comment: Aniket thakur, i am quite a beginner. I can post any question in stack overflow when ever i want because no matter the question is small or big, it has an answer and on top of that you dont have to teach something which i already know.Excused!

Comment: Thanks Slaks, JavaNewb. I found my mistake. cheers for java !

Answer (score 5):

`m` is a `MovieObjects`, which doesn't have a `name` field.

Did you mean `Movie`?

Also, you should make the fields `public` if you want to access them from other classes.
(although that's not actually necessary in the same package)

Comment: yes i realised my mistake. I mean movie and i did not create a new object of that class and ended up doing wrong access ! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Movie` class has those attribute, `MovieObjects` does not. Are you looking for

```
Movie m = new Movie();
```

instead of

```
MovieObjects m = new MovieObjects ();
```

Comment: Oh yes jlordo . I was such a silly. I need to create a new object of movie class not Movie Objects.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Movie {
     String name;
     String genre;
     int num;

     public void play()
     {
         System.out.println("start playing");
     }
}

public class MovieObjects{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie m = new Movie();
        {
            m.name="Killer"; 
            m.genre = "Romance";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With questions like this, we need to **explain** the problem; not hand him the answer on a silver platter.

Comment: Sorry, but when I can't see any effort in a question, I won't put any effort in the answer.

Comment: BTW: I don't see that silver platter in my answer. You still have to look for the difference for yourself. In this manner, your answer is the silver platter. :)

Comment: You're assuming that the OP won't just blindly paste in your code.

Answer (score 0):

name and  genre are variables of Movie class.So if you want to access them then create a Movie object and access them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no instance variable **name** in class **MovieObjects**. Your code makes no sense at all.
Here is the proper code.

```
  public class Movie 
  {
     public String name;
     public String genre;
     public int num;

     public void play()
     {
         System.out.println("start playing");
     }
  }
  public class MovieObjects
  {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.name="Killer"; 
        m.genre = "Romance"; 
     }
  }
```

But note this is **wrong way** to handle instance variable. Your instance variables must be defined **private** and must be altered only by **getter** and **setter** methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the "name" and "genre" are defined in Movie class not MovieObject class. Therefore, trying to access them from an object of MovieObject causes a "cannot find symbol" compile error. Change the line:

```
MovieObjects m = new MovieObjects ();
```

to

```
Movie m = new Movie();
```

Second, the curly brackets around the two assignment statements are redundant. Can be removed:

```
Movie m = new Movie();
 {
  m.name="Killer"; 
  m.genre = "Romance";
 }
```

should be changed to

```
 Movie m = new Movie();
 m.name="Killer"; 
 m.genre = "Romance";
```

Third, consider using setter and getter methods to access member variables.